# How to avoid terminal to catch error instead of Symfony profiler

Tags: symfony, error-handling, terminal, command-line-interface, php-builtin-server

**[edited on 19th june] The question is not regarding the content of the logs, but why logs doesn't not appear in my symfony profiler**

My symfony profiler doesn't display any error log but my php built-in-server seems to catch them and display them in my terminal.

To run my built-in web server, i'm using the following command: `php bin/console server:run` with no extra parameters

the output in my terminal is something like:

```
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [info] Matched route "overblog_graphql_endpoint".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Checking for guard authentication credentials.
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Checking support on guard authenticator.
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Calling getCredentials() on guard authenticator.
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [info] Guard authentication failed.
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] The "Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Guard\JWTTokenAuthenticator" authenticator set the response. Any later authenticator will not be called
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Overblog\GraphQLBundle\EventListener\ClassLoaderListener::load".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\ResolveControllerNameSubscriber::onKernelRequest".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener::onKernelRequest".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener::onKernelRequest" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.request".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelResponse".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onFinishRequest".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate".
[Wed Jun 19 09:23:21 2019] 127.0.0.1:60635 [401]: /
```

When I check my symfony profiler, i got this empty screen:
[image: Symfony Profiler]
<sub>(source: [i.ibb.co](https://i.ibb.co/8M109cx/profiler.png))</sub>

I remember long time ago, I run a command in my terminal to change the verbosity, but I'm unfortunately unable to remember which one was it to revert it. And I think this is the reason why the terminal is displaying the log info instead of my symfony profiler

Is there someone who can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no error shown in your output from terminal. It states that authentication failed and it won't let your HTTP request pass security component. That's why you are getting HTTP response `401 Unauthorized`.

```
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [info] Guard authentication failed.
2019-06-19T07:23:21+00:00 [debug] The "Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\Guard\JWTTokenAuthenticator" authenticator set the response. Any later authenticator will not be called
```

You have issue in your application security config which is not letting any request through. That's why Symfony profiler is empty and why you cannot reach the website. Though this is not an `Exception` which could be thrown. It's simply required behavior based on your particular config and sent request.

Also any change to verbosity of the command (parameter `-v[vv]`) is not permanent and is relevant only during the run of that particular command.

Comment: when in debug mode, the profiler should show the logs even without if no error. All those entries should be shown like this: !(http://i.imgur.com/lM1K0Bg.gif) (see https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-1-web-debug-toolbar-and-profiler-enhancements)

Comment: changing -v[vv] doesn't change anything

Comment: as i said, your security is actually not letting profiler through, try to turn it off completely

Answer (score 0):

ok, i was just missing monolog (`composer require symfony/monolog-bundle`)

By doing so, my terminal only show this:

```
[Wed Jun 19 11:56:26 2019] 127.0.0.1:53057 [200]: /graphiql
[Wed Jun 19 11:56:27 2019] 127.0.0.1:53058 [200]: /
[Wed Jun 19 11:56:28 2019] 127.0.0.1:53059 [200]: /_wdt/ddb809
[Wed Jun 19 11:56:30 2019] 127.0.0.1:53062 [200]: /graphiql
[Wed Jun 19 11:56:30 2019] 127.0.0.1:53063 [200]: /
[Wed Jun 19 11:56:30 2019] 127.0.0.1:53065 [200]: /_wdt/4f2a47
[Wed Jun 19 11:56:33 2019] 127.0.0.1:53068 [200]: /
[Wed Jun 19 11:56:42 2019] 127.0.0.1:53074 [200]: /_profiler/ea688f
[Wed Jun 19 11:56:43 2019] 127.0.0.1:53075 [200]: /_profiler/ea688f?panel=logger
```

and my logs are appearing normally in my symfony profiler